# how to combine php routing and seo

Tags: php, routes, seo

Let's assume that we have a news website, and it uses routing, for example the query:

```
    127.0.0.1/news/index.php?id=33
```

looks like

```
    127.0.0.1/news/33
```

and we select * from table where id=33 to view the details.
but how would Google find it? Should I write a dynamic meta tag? like:

```
    <meta name="description" content="'.$row['title'].'"/>
```

or what? I'm afraid that my website news wont be recognized by spiders.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Search engines see what humans see.

Comment: do you mean that every time I add an entry to my table, SEs recognizes it dynamically?

Comment: Can a human see it when you do that? Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [url rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

..I'm not sure, but this *should* work, I have never used it before :/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: That's what I'm using, I'm just wondering if Search Engines can find it, and if I have to add meta tags as I've explained above

Comment: You need to add title and meta description tags specific to every page. You have to do it dynamically. So for every news item of your site you need to specify title and description in your database.